how to restrict Azure AD SPN permission with Databricks?
Hello I m using Data bricks,
and
working with https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/statementexecution
I m using SQL Api statement with help of Azure ADAP SPN token.
I m able to run all queries successfully.
https://medium.com/@masterkeshav/consuming-databricks-sql-on-azure-service-user-principals-with-row-column-level-security-5618377bd0ec
I want to restrict this SPN to use only  to read Data.
If I Use any delete query or any query apart of read operation I don't want to allow to  that SPN.
I also dont want to allow that SPN to Do any DML operation or delete job or cluster or Wearhouse kind job.
I just want that SPN to allow to read data.
Any one have done this

How are you doing generating token. please add those details.

string clientId = "xxx-xxx-x-xxxxx";
string clientSecret = "*******************";
string resourceUrl = "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d"; //MS Resource Identifier for Databricks
#################################
ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(ClientId)
.WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
.WithAuthority(Authority)
.Build();
its standard Microsoft Code
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/web-apps-apis/authorization-codes

You can restrict the service principal for SQL query execution at the schema level and the table level.
To grant such permission follow below steps:
Go To > Catalog > Select schema or table > Permissions > Grant

After clicking on "Grant," you will see the window below.

Here, search for the service principal you previously added and grant only select permission.

This restricts the service principal to read-only access for an object.

Can we do this by api call rather to do manually ? setting permission on schema or table

check this https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/grants/update

thank you for this information. and is it possible to use user manage identity replacing SPN?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/auth/azure-mi

Yes you can use. While adding managed identity to workspace you give application I'd of your user managed identity

Implementation testing is in progress so just waiting for result]t

i hope it worked for you.
